# Java Streams: Replacing groupingBy and reducing by toMap

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, collectors, reducing

I've asked a question before about enhancing some code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684523/do-i-need-a-custom-spliterator-to-avoid-extra-stream-call). [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) gives me the right response and he said that:

> Whenever you find yourself using the reducing collector with
>   groupingBy, you should check whether toMap isn’t more appropriate

It seems like a pattern ! and what he suggests me to do was just perfect.

Is this a well known pattern ?  Why `toMap` is better than (in some cases) combining `groupingBy` and `reducing` ?

Comment: I think it's just common sense and `Collectors` knowledge, nothing like a pattern if you ask me.

Comment: "Anyone can tel me how he figured this out ?" I'd guess Holger would be the best person to ask!

Comment: @ElmaCherb commenting again on that answer (using `@Holger`) would notify him directly. It was several weeks ago, so he is unlikely to revisit the question unless prompted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This pattern became evident by experience with using both collectors. You’ll find several Q&As on Stackoverflow, where a problem could be solved with either collector, but one of them seems a better fit for the particular task.

This is a variation of the difference between [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction). In the first case, we use `reduce` on the Stream, in the second we use `collect`. It comes naturally, that the `groupingBy` collector, which takes a second `Collector` as argument, is the right tool when we want to apply a Mutable Reduction to the groups.

Not that obviously, the `toMap` collector taking a *merge* function is the right tool when we want to perform a classical Reduction, as that merge function has the same shape and purpose as a Reduction function, even if it is not called as such.

In practice, we note that the collectors which perform a Reduction, return an `Optional`, which is usually not desired when being used with `groupingBy`, which is the reason why `toMap` works more smoothly in these cases.

There are surely more patterns which become apparent while using these APIs, but collecting them in one answer is not the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. I have read this time and time again. How about detailing those 'more patterns' in a blog or sharing links to some existing articles?

Comment: @Naman maybe I should start writing a blog…

Comment: Indeed, in some cases, it might not seem very obvious that `toMap` with a merge function is the right tool. But it really makes a difference in terms of readability. Very instructive observation.