# How to Convert a List Into Map of Map Map<String, Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a `List<Employee>` e which I want to convert into 
`Map<String, Map<String,Emp>>`  where the outer string should be "Name" and the inner string should be "Domain".

```
       Name Id Domain
e(0) - Emp1, 1, Insurance
e(1) - Emp1, 2, Sales
e(2) - Emp2, 3, Sales
e(3) - Emp4, 4, Marketing
```

I am tried the following-

```
e.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                   Employee::getName,
                                   toMap(Employee::getDomain,Emp)));
```

So the expected output map should look like

```
<Emp1>
     <Insurance, e(0)>
     <Sales, e(1)>
<Emp2>
     <Sales, e(2)>
<Emp4>
     <Marketing, e(3)>
```

But I get only unique values, actual output-

```
<Emp1>
     <Insurance, e(0)>
<Emp2>
     <Sales, e(2)>
<Emp4>
     <Marketing, e(3)>
```

Can someone tell the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are mostly looking for is nested grouping such as :

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Employee>>> groupedMap = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDomain, Collectors.toList())));
```

*Note* - The values are `List<Employee>` which are the employees grouped by name and then by domain. (Both same clubbed into a List.)

---

If you were to stricly adhere to getting a single employee corresponding to the specified grouping, the code pretty much works for me with a small modification:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> groupedReducedMap = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                Collectors.toMap(Employee::getDomain,
                        Function.identity(), // value as the employee instance
                        (a, b) -> a))); // choose first instance for similar 'domain'
```

Comment: Thanks, for the required data structure the second one works

Answer (score 0):

Since the output should be `Map<String, Map<String,Employee>>` and not `Map<String, Map<String,List<Employee>>>` (i.e. based on your requested output, there cannot be two `Employee`s having the same name and the same domain), you can chain two `groupingBy` and then use `reducing` to ensure that each inner group will have a single `Employee` instead of a `List<Employee>`:

```
Map<String, Map<String,Optional<Employee>>> output =
    e.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                                    Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDomain,
                                                          Collectors.reducing((x1,x2)->x2))));
```

The problem with this version of `reducing` is that it returns an `Optional<Employee>` instead of `Employee`, even though we know the `Optional` will never be empty.

We get can around that with:

```
  Map<String, Map<String,Employee>> output =
      e.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName,
                                      Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDomain,
                                                            Collectors.reducing(e.get(0),
                                                                                (x1,x2)->x2))));
```

Now, we use a variant of `reducing` having an identity value, to which we pass an arbitrary `Employee` instance (it doesn't matter which, since it will always be replaced by the correct instance).

Comment: IIRC, sometime back Holger pointed this out, that `toMap` is preferable to `groupingBy + reducing`. Here - [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap)