# Java: construct a map aggregating its value if key is present

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, grouping, collectors

I have a list of GroupItem objects:

```
public class GroupItem {
    Group group;
    BigDecimal value;
    ...
}
```

What I want to achieve is a Map where value for the same Group key is aggregated. I implemented it in the following way (slightly refactored variant, but still far from being elegant):

```
List<GroupItem> items = generateGroupItemList();

Map<Group, BigDecimal> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (GroupItem item : items) {
        resultMap.put(item.getGroup(), resultMap.getOrDefault(item.getGroup(), BigDecimal.ZERO).add(item.getValue()));
    }
```

This variant looks ugly and lacks readability. I tried using streams, but didn't achieve any positive result. The general idea was around Collectors.groupingBy() and something like this:

```
items.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                GroupItem::getGroup,
                Collectors.reducing(GroupItem:getValue, /*BigDecimal::add*/)
));
```

Is there more elegant way to achieve desired effect, besides the variant above?

Comment: Just to remind me: [Replacing `groupingBy` and `reducing` by `toMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap) you can achieve it as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58882379/1746118).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Stream`, you can perform `toMap` with `Collectors`:

```
Map<Group, BigDecimal> resultMap = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(GroupItem::getGroup,
                GroupItem::getValue, BigDecimal::add));
```

Comment: As a stream approach it is very compact and nice solution. I forgot that Collectors.toMap() has BinaryOperator arg for merging.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
  List<GroupItem> items = generateGroupItemList();

  Map<Group, BigDecimal> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
  for (GroupItem item : items) {
    resultMap.merge(item.getGroup(), item.getValue(), BigDecimal::add);
  }
```

Comment: I changed the example in the question to be one-line and less ugly, but still far from being ideal. And your answer makes it perfect. Thank you.