# Which Collectors to use?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Regarding those classes I’m trying to build a Map :

With these simple classes structures

```
class Alert {

     public String serie;
     public String rame;
     public String label;

     public Alert( String serie, String rame, String label ) {
         this.serie = serie;
         this.rame = rame;
         this.label = label;
     }

     public String getSerie() {
         return serie;
     }

     public String getRame() {
         return rame;
     }

     public String getLabel() {
         return label;
     }
}

 class Diagnostic {
    public String serie;
    public String rame;

    public List< Event > events;

    public Diagnostic(String serie, String rame){
         this.serie = serie;
         this.rame = rame;
    }

    public void addEvent(String label){
         if(events == null)events = new ArrayList<>(  );
         events.add( new Event( label ) );
    }
 }

class Event {

    public String label;

    public Event(String label){
         this.label = label;
     )}
 }


 Alert atgv1 = new Alert( "tgv", "rame1", "label1" );
 Alert atgv2 = new Alert( "tgv", "rame1", "label2" );
 Alert atgv3 = new Alert( "tgv", "rame1" , "label3");

 Alert atgv4 = new Alert( "tgv", "rame2", "label4" );
 Alert atgv5 = new Alert( "tgv", "rame2", "label5" );

 Alert atgv6 = new Alert( "tgv", "rame3", "label6" );

 Alert az2n1 = new Alert( "z2n", "rame1", "label1" );
 Alert az2n2 = new Alert( "z2n", "rame1", "label2" );
 Alert az2n3 = new Alert( "z2n", "rame1" , "label3");

 Alert az2n4 = new Alert( "z2n", "rame2", "label4" );
 Alert az2n5 = new Alert( "z2n", "rame2", "label5" );
 Alert az2n6 = new Alert( "z2n", "rame3", "label6" );

 List<Alert> alerts = Arrays.asList(atgv1, atgv2, atgv3, atgv4, atgv5, atgv6, az2n1, az2n2, az2n3, az2n4, az2n5, az2n6);
```

I have this code that works :

```
Map<String, Map<String, Diagnostic>> map = alerts.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.groupingBy( Alert::getSerie,
                    Collectors.toMap( Alert::getRame,  a -> new Diagnostic( a.getSerie(), a.getRame() ), (a1, a2) -> a1)), b -> {

                b.forEach( ( k, v ) -> v.forEach( ( y, z)  -> {
                    List<Alert> found = alerts.stream().filter( p -> p.getSerie().equals( k ) && p.getRame().equals( y ) ).collect( Collectors.toList());

                    found.forEach( f -> z.addEvent( f.getLabel() ) );
                }) );
                return b;
            } ));
```

The result is what I want however the problem is that I’m looping on the maps in the `andThen` in order to find the right alert (filter) and add the event (.addEvent)

How to achieve it in one time? Is it possible without coding my own `Collector`? 
The difficult part is that I want a single Diagnostic with its List of Event and NOT a List of Diagnostic that i can easily achieve with a second `groupingBy` instead of the `toMap`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach the problem with multiple `groupingBy`, what you would then be looking for is `reducing` the `Diagnostic` values:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Optional<Diagnostic>>> map = alerts.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Alert::getSerie,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Alert::getRame,
            Collectors.mapping(e -> new Diagnostic(e.getSerie(), e.getRame()),
                Collectors.reducing((d1, d2) -> Diagnostic.builder()
                    .serie(d1.getSerie())
                    .rame(d1.getRame())
                    .events(Stream.concat(d1.getEvents().stream(),
                        d2.getEvents().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .build())))));
```

*Note*: The above relies on the `Builder` that I've used for the convenience of creating the instance of `Diagnostic` involving the addition of events and it collects the innermost values as `Optional` for the lack of identity element to fall back upon.

Or as annswered by Holger, [using `toMap(f1, f2, f3)` instead of `groupingBy(f1, mapping(f2, reducing(f3)))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap) would be a preferred operation for the nested collecting operation, as in:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Diagnostic>> map = alerts.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Alert::getSerie,
        Collectors.toMap(Alert::getRame, e -> new Diagnostic(e.getSerie(), e.getRame()),
            (d1, d2) -> Diagnostic.builder()
                .serie(d1.getSerie())
                .rame(d1.getRame())
                .events(Stream.concat(d1.getEvents().stream(),
                    d2.getEvents().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .build())));
```