# How to use groupingBy, sort and reduce on a List of objects in streams

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have a List of objects `List<FloatBalance>` which can be represented by the following JSON. I want to get the most **recent entry** for each **currency** in the List and pass the pruned list back to the request.

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "clientId": 50,
        "currency": "GBP",
        "floatType": "ChargeFloat",
        "floatCurrentValue": 300.00,
        "chargeReference": "PROD-1578486576_278",
        "cashOutReference": null,
        "cashInReference": null,
        "targetValue": 3000.00,
        "alertValue": 500.00,
        "maxValue": 4500.00,
        "createdDate": "2020-01-08T12:29:50Z"
    },
...
]
```

My first attempt is straight foward, I group them by currency with

```
Map<String, List<FloatBalance>> result = floats.stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(FloatBalance::getCurrency));
```

and then I group them and order them by most recent date with

```
Map<String, List<FloatBalance>> floatGrouped = floats.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FloatBalance::getCreatedDate).reversed())
                    .collect(groupingBy(FloatBalance::getCurrency));
```

**Map Result**

[image]

I can also reduce the list but I have only been able to carry out this operation on the complete list which returns only the most recent entry.

```
FloatBalance floatGrouped = floats.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FloatBalance::getCreatedDate))
                    .reduce((first, second) -> second)
                    .orElse(null);
```

I have gone round in circles trying to figure this out, I've tried to `.entrySet()` to carry out reduce on each entry in the map but computer says no to everything I've tried.

Ideally I want to retrun the most recent entry for each currency as the system response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for :

```
List<FloatBalance> result = floats.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FloatBalance::getCurrency,
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(FloatBalance::getCreatedDate))))
        .values().stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I have a lot of reading to do, I tried everything you have in your working answer but obviously I had the actions in the wrong order. Thank you.

Comment: You can `filter` values that are not present. Having said that, it's one thing I feel is overhead while using reduction, unless a significant identity element is defined.

Comment: @Naman you mean `.values().stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)`

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, instead of allowing `null` values in the `List`.

Comment: every time you have to deal with an `Optional` from `Collectors.maxBy` what you are _really_ looking for is `BinaryOperator::max/minBy`

Comment: @chrisloughnane this answer, while correct, does some operations that can be elided.

Comment: @Eugene Indeed. I have also moved slowly into thinking in the direction of [replacing `groupingBy` and `reducing` by `toMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap). Not saying always, but deciding before implementing.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<FloatBalance> floatBalances = new ArrayList<>(floats.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                FloatBalance::getCurrency,
                Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(FloatBalance:: getCreatedDate))))
        .values());
```

First, this collects to a `Map`, where Key is `currency` and value is `floatBalanace`. When *two* currencies collide, there is a merger that will separate them - or tell which to pick. This is what `BinaryOperator::maxBy`. does. It basically says : "I will take one of the two floatBalancers where createdDate is the biggest".  And, at the end, you simply take `values` - which will return a `Collection<FloatBalance>`.

Comment: @naman why did you edit to incorrect getCreatedAt ? getCreatedDate is correct, I guess

Comment: What does `Function.identity()` do in this example? Everything else I can understand, but I'm not sure what purpose this serves.

Comment: @Eoin chooses a `FloatBalance` itself as the value and then for the next value that appears with the same key, gets compared within the `maxBy`

Comment: @EugeneKortov that was just a typo, the edit was meant to improve the code readability and completeness primarily.