# java 8 stream collect max object and distinct by Property

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

Some List is here

```
List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
{
   list.add(new Book("Core Java", 200));
   list.add(new Book("Core Java", 500));
   list.add(new Book("Core Java", 800));
   list.add(new Book("Learning Freemarker", 150));          
   list.add(new Book("Learning Freemarker", 1350));   
   list.add(new Book("Learning Freemarker", 1250));   
   list.add(new Book("Spring MVC", 300));
   list.add(new Book("Spring MVC", 600)); 
   list.add(new Book("Spring MVC", 1600));
}
```

I want show Book list like this

```
Core Java", 800
Learning Freemarker", 1350
Spring MVC", 1600
```

each 1element

```
list .stream().distinct()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Book::bookname)
     .thenComparing(Book::getPrice)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this code only sorted.

Comment: Please show the code of the `Book` class. Do you have `equals` and `hashCode` overridden in it?

Comment: Book is sample Class
`private string bookname ;
private  string price;` 
it is done;

Comment: @user3066285 - What @ernest_k is primarily interested in is the `equals` and `hashcode` implementation if you've overridden them because of the use of `distinct` in your sample code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you can do a group by on `Book` name and collect them into `Map<String, List<Book>>`, And then from `map.values()` collect the highest price book from each type

```
List<Book> books = list.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Book::getName))
                       .values()
                       .stream()
                       .map(book -> Collections.max(book, Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getCost)))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The other solution suggested by @Holger using `Collectors.toMap` will be more effective comparing to collecting and finding the max element

```
List<Book> books = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(Book::getName, Function.identity(),
                            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getCost))),
                    m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

Comment: Thank you. you save my time.

Comment: One could have used `grouping` with `reduce` as well to perform the comparison in one collect operation and then further get the values out of it. As I can recall and relate, it's still better to use `toMap` instead of such a grouping and reduce combination. Linking the [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap) again.

Comment: In short, `List<Book> books = list.stream() .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.toMap(Book::getName, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy( Comparator.comparing(Book::getPrice))), m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));`

Comment: Thanks @Holger i was trying something similar to this but you got it

Answer (score 2):

The distinct and then using sorting implies that all distinct books (not just by name) would be selected, further sorting then would still not remove the other entries in the input list until you reduce them somehow. Further based on the desired output, that shouldn't be the way to go.

Instead what you can seek for is using `bookName` as an attribute to check for uniqueness and then merging the books comparing their prices and collecting them to our final result.

A fairly simple code to what you're looking forwards to would be using `toMap` such as:

```
List<Book> distinctMaxPriceBooks = new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Book::getBookName, Function.identity(),
                (b1, b2) -> b1.getPrice() >= b2.getPrice() ? b1 : b2))
        .values());
```

Of course, these can be sorted based on the name if that was anyhow the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One version that makes use of the `max` method and prints sorted results.

```
 list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Book::getaString))
        .values()
        .stream()
            .map( (books) -> books.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getaNumber)).get())
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getaNumber))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```