# Java Filters Finding the most expensive house in each City

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-stream

I have a list of houses in a number of cities. I am trying to use a filter in order to generate a list of the most expensive house in each city. I am unable to use conventional loops.

```
//This returns unique City Names
List unique = obList.stream()
    .map(x -> x.getCity())
    .distinct()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

//This returns the house with the highest price in that city
RAddress obReturn = obList.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(sName))
        .sorted((x,y) -> (int)(y.getPrice() - x.getPrice()))
        .findFirst()
        .get();
```

I understand that combining these in some way is necessary to this problem but I cannot for the life of me figure out how...

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `groupingBy` collector to collect all the houses in each city together; then use a downstream `maxBy` collector to keep just the most expensive house in each city:

```
obList.stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy(
            x -> x.getCity(),
            maxBy(comparing(x -> x.getPrice())))
```

This returns a `Map<CityType, Optional<HouseType>>` (where `CityType` and `HouseType` are whatever the types of cities and houses are, respectively.

If you want a `Map<CityType, HouseType>` (that is, without the `Optional`, since you know the value is always present), wrap the downstream collector:

```
collectingAndThen(maxBy(...), Optional::get)
```

Comment: the "MaxBy" appears to not be a keyword, i must be doing something wrong.

Comment: [`maxBy` is a method in the `Collectors` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-), as is `groupingBy`.

Comment: @user11376058 Just to be explicit, the above code relies on `static import` from `Collectors` class with a return type of `Map<String, Optional<Integer>>` if your city is of `String` type and price being `Integer`.

Comment: Or use `toMap(x -> x.getCity(), Function.identity(), maxBy(comparing(x -> x.getPrice())))`, now using [`BinaryOperator.maxBy(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#maxBy(java.util.Comparator)). Then you don’t need to deal with `Optional`. See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57041896/2711488)…