# Java - Merge objects of list given a condition

Tags: java, java-stream

I uttlerly convinced that my question its quite simple but im unable to do it with streams (if there is a way to do it without stream will be helpfull too)
Suppose that we have this list of users

```
public class Users {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   double accountBalance;
   String type;
   String extraField;
}
```

and suppose that we have the following data in my List < Users >

```
"Users": [{
            "firstName": "Scott",
            "lastName": "Salisbury",
            "accountBalance": "100",
            "type" : "A"
        }, {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Richards",
            "accountBalance": "200",
            "type" :"C"

        }, {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Richards",
            "accountBalance": "200",
            "type " : "C",
            "ExtraField": "Apply"
        }]
```

the expected result here its given that firstName, lastName and type appears twice on the list just merge the results that are common without missing any field 
Expected output

```
"Users": [{
            "firstName": "Scott",
            "lastName": "Salisbury",
            "accountBalance": "100",
            "type" : "A"
        }, {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Richards",
            "accountBalance": "400",//merged values
            "type " : "C",
            "ExtraField": "Apply" //value that remains in one object of the list
        }]
```

Comment: How many fields could be there in the bean?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare this a example , with this supose 5 fields

Comment: Are you using any libraries for manipulating this data? For example, [JSON-Simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)?

Comment: @TimHunter what i what to merge its just a List<Users> , i will update to give more details

Comment: You can first group them using `groupingBy` with a function extracting the key fields; this gives you a list of users by key. Those you can then merge by giving a downstream collector.

Comment: All you need to do is implement a method `public User mergeSimilarUsers(User user, User anotherUser);`, rest would be a simple *collection to a `Map`* based on *keys for uniqueness* and *extracting the values* from it as a result. Give

Comment: @daniu Or simply use `toMap` with the method as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @Naman I keep forgetting `toMap` because I learned `groupingBy` first :/

Comment: @daniu Sure, let's [remember it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap) then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a key class containing the three fields, like

```
@Data
class UserKey {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String type;

    static UserKey from(User user) { /* TODO (trivial) */ }
}
```

**groupingBy**

Those can be used to group your users

```
Map<UserKey,List<User>> grouped = 
    users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserKey::from));
```

Each of these lists can then be merged by

```
Optional<User> summed = userList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.reducing((u1, u2) -> {
        u1.setAccountBalance(u1.accountBalance() + u2.accountBalance());
    });
```

This can also be given directly as a downstream collector to the `groupingBy`:

```
Map<UserKey,Optional<User>> mergedMap = 
    users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserKey::from,
        Collectors.reducing((u1, u2) -> {
            u1.setAccountBalance(u1.accountBalance() + u2.accountBalance());
            return u1;
        }));
```

Since those `Optional`s are guaranteed to be filled, you can just call `get()` on them; also, you don't need the keys anymore, so

```
List<User> result = mergedMap.values().stream()
                 .map(Optional::get)
                 .collect(toList());
```

**toMap**

As Naman suggested in the comments, you can also shortcut this by `toMap`.

```
Map<UserKey,User> mergedMap = users.stream()
    .collect(toMap(UserKey::from, Function.identity(), 
        (u1, u2) -> {
            u1.setAccountBalance(u1.accountBalance() + u2.accountBalance());
            return u1;
        }));
List<User> result = new ArrayList<>(mergedMap.values());
```

Note that the reducing function has the side effect of manipulating one of the original user objects in the list, so make sure you don't need them again.

Comment: Isn't that Collectors.toMap() ?? and I'm getting Cannot resolve method 'identity' error, any idea ??

Comment: You should not use a method reference. You should use Function.identity().

If you use a method reference, you're basically trying to pass a Supplier<Function<T, T>>.

Comment: @Ramana corrected, thanks. I use and imply static imports for the `Collectors` methods.

Comment: First of all UserKey Method "from" is not trivial for those who need help here. And Second you have a ")" too much in every example.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is just Lists of Objects, then you should be able to merge the data fairly straight forward with a few loops. For example:

```
public static ArrayList<User> mergeData(ArrayList<User> userList) {
  ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>(userList);

  for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
      User currentUser = users.get(i);
      for(int j = i + 1; j < users.size(); j++) {
          User otherUser = users.get(j);

          if(currentUser.firstName.equals(otherUser.firstName) 
            && currentUser.lastName.equals(otherUser.lastName)
            && currentUser.type.equals(otherUser.type)) {
                //Apply the field merging
                currentUser.accountBalance += otherUser.accountBalance;
                if(currentUser.extraField == null) {
                    currentUser.extraField = otherUser.extraField;
                } else {
                    //Handle case where you pick whether to keep the value or not.
                }

                //Remove the merged data and move index back to account for removal
                users.remove(j);
                j--;
           }
      }
  }

  return users;
}
```

The code just runs through the values, compares it against every other remaining value in the list, merges where applicable, and then removes the merged object from the rest of the list before moving on to the next value.