# How do I add up and remove repeated objects from ArrayList?

Tags: java, java-8

**User Detail model:**

```
private String userName;
private int userSalary;
```

**I've a ArrayList of user information**

```
List<UserDetail> userDetails = new ArrayList<>();

UserDetail user1 = new UserDetail("Robert", 100);
UserDetail user2 = new UserDetail("John", 100);
UserDetail user3 = new UserDetail("Robert", 55);

userdetails.add(user1);
userdetails.add(user2);
userdetails.add(user3);
```

I'm trying to iterate through the array and find out if there are any duplicate entries based on `userName`, from the above list I've two records with same user name `"Robert"`, in this case I want to add up the `userSalary` and remove one record from the List.

**Expected new ArrayList:**

```
userName userSalary

Robert 155
John 100
```

Is this possible ??

Comment: You add three times the same `user1` to the list. Is it ok?

Comment: You could use a map with key as userName and value as userSalary to help you aggregate the salaries for the same user.

Comment: @Uata updated my post, that should be user1, user2 and user3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Merge objects of list given a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415626/java-merge-objects-of-list-given-a-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 userDetails.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        UserDetail::getName,
                        Function.identity(),
                        (left, right) -> {
                            left.setSalary(left.getSalary() + right.getSalary());
                            return left;
                        }
                    ))
            .values();
```

This will give you a `Collection<UserDetail>`.  You can copy that into an `ArrayList` if needed, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Because your goal is to group `UserDetail` objects that share the same `userName`, I recommend storing the result in a `Map` instead of an `ArrayList`.

This is possible by streaming your `List` and collecting it to a `Map` using [`Collectors#groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) in conjunction with [`Collectors#summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)):

```
List<UserDetail> userDetails = new ArrayList<>();

UserDetail user1 = new UserDetail("Robert", 100);
UserDetail user2 = new UserDetail("John", 100);
UserDetail user3 = new UserDetail("Robert", 55);

userDetails.add(user1);
userDetails.add(user2);
userDetails.add(user3);

Map<String, Integer> groupedUserDetails = userDetails.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserDetail::getUserName,
        Collectors.summingInt(UserDetail::getUserSalary)));

System.out.println(groupedUserDetails);
```

This above snippet may output the following:

```
{Robert=155, John=100}
```

---

If you want to convert this `Map<String, Integer>` into a `List<UserDetail>`, then you can use the following:

```
List<UserDetail> newUserDetails = groupedUserDetails.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> new UserDetail(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: that is `Map<String, Integer>` though, not a `List/Collection<UserDetail>` as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without streams(may be easier to understand):

```
Iterator<UserDetail> it=userDetails.iterator();
Map<String,UserDetail> found=new HashMap<>();
while(it.hasNext()){
    UserDetail next=it.next();
    if(found.containsKey(next.getUserName())){
        found.get(next.getUserName()).setUserSalery(found.get(next.getUserName()).getUserSalery()+next.getUserSalery();
        it.remove();
    }
    else{
        found.put(next.getUserName(),next);
    }
}
```

This iterates through all elements.

If it has already found a matching element, it adds its own salery to it and removes itself out of the list.

If not, it marks itself to be found if other elemts are found with the same name later.

This assumes that `UserDetail` has standard getter/setter methods for `userName` and `userSalery`.

Note that a for-each loop cannot be used because you cannot modify the content of the List in there (it would throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`).

From the comments(from @[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger):

> You can use a single `UserDetail previous = found.putIfAbsent(next.getName());`, followed by `if(previous != null) { previous.setSalery(previous.getSalery()+next.getSalery()); it.remove(); }` instead of looking up the map three times in a row.

That code would be:

```
Iterator<UserDetail> it=userDetails.iterator();
Map<String,UserDetail> found=new HashMap<>();
while(it.hasNext()){
    UserDetail next=it.next();
    UserDetail previous = found.putIfAbsent(next.getUserName());
    if(previous != null) {
        previous.setUserSalery(previous.getUserSalery()+next.getUserSalery());
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

This essentially does the same thing.

It adds the current element to the List if it does not exist and if not, it just adds up the salery.

Comment: You can use a single `UserDetail previous = found.putIfAbsent(next.getName());`, followed by `if(previous != null) { previous.setSalery(previous.getSalery()+next.getSalery()); it.remove(); }` instead of looking up the map three times in a row.

Comment: @Holger I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an alternate approach. HashMap

- Use username as key
- override equals & hashcode
- Before adding an element to the hashMap, check if any object already present
- If object found, get salary from it, update the current object, and then add to map

---

```
public class UserDetail {
    private String userName;
    private int userSalary;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.userName.equals(((UserDetail)obj).userName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return userName.length();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `Map` is used to store `UserDetail` by `userName`. If user is in map salary will be add up and update in the map. Other wise user will be put in the map. Finally the map values will be converted to a `UserDetail` list

```
Map<String, UserDetail> mergedMap = new HashMap<>(); // username is used as the key 
userDetails.forEach(userDetail -> {
   String userName = userDetail.getUserName();
   UserDetail userInMap = mergedMap.get(userName);
   if (userInMap != null) { // if user is in map salary will be added
      userInMap.setUserSalary(userInMap.getUserSalary() + userDetail.getUserSalary());
   } else { //otherwise user will put in map
      mergedMap.put(userDetail.getUserName(), userDetail);
   }
});

List<UserDetail> usersWithMergedSalaries = new ArrayList<>(mergedMap.values()); //convert map values to a list
```