# How avoid duplicates in result from stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

**CashBox class:**

```
public class CashBox {
    private long cashBoxId;
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;
    private long merchantId;

    // all-args constructor
}
```

***Merchant class:***

```
public class Merchant {
    private long merchantId;
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;

   // all-args constructor
}
```

***Input data:***

```
List<CashBox> cashBoxes = List.of(
    new CashBox(1, new BigDecimal(1000), 1),
    new CashBox(2, new BigDecimal(2000), 1),
    new CashBox(3, new BigDecimal(3000), 2),
    new CashBox(4, new BigDecimal(500), 2));
```

***My task***

> Calculate the total amount for each merchant and return the merchant list

I'm trying to solve this task using Stream API. And wrote the following code:

```
List<Merchant> merchant =  cashBoxes.stream()
    .map(merch -> new Merchant(
        merch.getMerchantId(), 
        cashBoxes.stream()
                 .filter(cashBox -> cashBox.getMerchantId() == merch.getMerchantId())
                 .map(CashBox::getTotalAmount)
                 .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

***Result***

```
[Merchant{merchantId=1, totalAmount=3000}, Merchant{merchantId=1, totalAmount=3000}, Merchant{merchantId=2, totalAmount=3500}, Merchant{merchantId=2, totalAmount=3500}]
```

But obviously, the stream returns four objects instead of the needed two.
I realize, that the map(2nd row) creates four objects for each cashBoxId. And I don't get how to filter by `merchantId` or get results without duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-). Group by the merchant Ids, then for each group, map to the total amount, and reduce, using the corresponding collectors. This will get you a `Map<Long, BigDecimal>` containing merchant Ids and total amounts. You can then map each entry of this map to a merchant:

```
cashBoxes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    CashBox::getMerchantId, // group by merchant Id
    // for each group...
    Collectors.mapping(// map to total amount
        CashBox::getTotalAmount,
        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add) // sum
    )
)).entrySet().stream()
    .map(x -> new Merchant(x.getKey(), x.getValue())) // map to merchant
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "one-liner" using a single Stream. The idea is to use the advantage of the grouping using `Stream::toMap`, mapping value using `Function<CashBox, Merchant>` and merging them into a single object using `BinaryOperator<Merchant>`:

```
Collection<Merchant> merchants = cashBoxes.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        CashBox::getMerchantId,
        cashBox -> new Merchant(cashBox.getMerchantId(), cashBox.getTotalAmount()),
        (l, r) -> {
            l.setTotalAmount(l.getTotalAmount().add(r.getTotalAmount()));
            return l;
        }
    ))
    .values();
```

Comment: 1. why would you need an `if..else`, are you not already reducing the list of cashboxes all of which have the same `merchantId`? 2. Use of [`toMap` would have simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap)

Comment: @Naman: I missed that! Thanks for the note!