# want to use groupBy,filter and max in java8 which can return the List<Object>

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have the `List<MyClassObject>` which i want to filter and apply some conditional check.
I want to apply groupingBy and filter if the values are not zero and get the maxBy.

Below is the sample code i was trying.

```
Map<Long,Optional<MyClassObject>> myObj =  obj.getMyClassObject().stream().
                                   filter(MyClassObject :: getStatus).
                                   collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyClassObject :: getClassStatusID,Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyClassObject::getStatusId))));
```

The above code filters the list with status as true and groupBy classStatusID and collects the max value of statusID for the particular classStatusID.
Is there any better approach for the above piece of code and the next step i want to perform is just i want the statusID value so that i can use that further. I was expecting some if the same can be done using `List<MyClassObject>` or any other best approach.

Comment: "Is there any better approach for the above piece of code" What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: `List<Long> idValues = obj.getMyClassObject().stream() .filter(MyClassObject::getStatus) .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collectors.toMap(MyClassObject::getClassStatusID, MyClassObject::getStatusId, Math::max), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));`. See [Replacing groupingBy and reducing by toMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57041896/2711488) and [the `values()` view of `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--)