# Create a Map of Optionals in Java using Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, option-type, collectors

I need to find a method (using streams) to return a `Map<Category,Optional<ToDo>`, which help me group an `ArrayList` and give me a `ToDo` object with the highest `priority` of each `category`.

```
public record ToDo(String name, Category category, 
                   int priority, LocalDate date) {}
```

```
public enum Category { HOME, WORK }
```

An example of the input data:

```
List<ToDo> todo = List.of(
    new ToDo("Eat", Category.HOME, 1, LocalDate.of(2022, 8, 29)),
    new ToDo("Sleep", Category.HOME, 2, LocalDate.of(2022, 8, 30)),
    new ToDo("Learn", Category.WORK, 2, LocalDate.of(2022, 9, 3)),
    new ToDo("Work", Category.WORK, 3, LocalDate.of(2022, 10, 3))
);
```

And in the end, I want to have something like this as a result:

```
{HOME=[ToDo{Description='Eat', category=HOME, priority=1, deadline=2022-08-29},
 WORK=[ToDo{Description='Learn', category=WORK, priority=2, deadline=2022-09-03]}
```

I was trying to use

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getCategory()));
```

and

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(ToDo::getPriority)).findFirst();
```

But I can't do it in a single method and get `Optional` as a result. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Optional in a deep hierarchy is not a good idea. Instead of mapping e.g. `Category.EAT` to an `Optional.NONE`, just.. not have that mapping.

Comment: It's not my idea, it's a requirement to make it as an Optional, in detail - Map<Category, Optional>

Comment: To be clear, you need an entry in the map for every value in `Category`, even if there's no `ToDo` with a particular `Category` in the initial list?

Comment: Hint: `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(ToDo::getPriority)).findFirst()` means `.minBy(Comparator.comparing(ToDo::getPriority))`

Answer (score 2):

The practice of storing `Optional`s in a `Collection` is **discouraged**.

It might seem as a smart move at first. But in fact you're creating a Map which give you a `null` or potentially empty Optional, which doesn't sound very handy.

Besides that it goes against the design goal of `Optional` which is intended to be used as a return type. Optional is meant only for transitioning data (not storing), for that reason it was designed non-serializable, and it might cause issues.

And for every *category* that would be encountered in the list, there always would be a corresponding `ToDo` object. If your intention was to have all members of `Category` in the map in order to be able to safely fire an action on the `Optional` returned by `get()` via `ifPresent()`, then instead you can implement [*Null-object pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) and map your null-object `ToDo` to every *category* that wasn't present in the list via `putIfAbsent()`.

If you want to find `ToDo` with the ***highest*** priority (***lowest*** value of priority) using *collector* `groupingBy()` as you've mentioned in the question. Then you can use *collector* [`minBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#minBy(java.util.Comparator)) in conjunction with a *collector* `collectingAndThen()` as a *downstream* of `groupingBy()`. It would be way more efficient than combination `.sorted().findFirst()`.

But since we need a single *value* mapped to each *key* (and not a collection of *values*) as *@Holger* has pointed out, the proper way of handling this task is by using *collector* [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) instead of `groupingBy()` + *downstream collectors*. It results in less verbose and more intuitive code.

```
List<ToDo> todo = List.of(
    new ToDo("Eat", Category.HOME, 1, LocalDate.of(2022, 8, 29)),
    new ToDo("Sleep", Category.HOME, 2, LocalDate.of(2022, 8, 30)),
    new ToDo("Learn", Category.WORK, 2, LocalDate.of(2022, 9, 3)),
    new ToDo("Work", Category.WORK, 3, LocalDate.of(2022, 10, 3))
);

Map<Category, ToDo> highestPriorityTaskByCategory = todo.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        ToDo::category,
        Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparingInt(ToDo::priority))
    ));

highestPriorityTaskByCategory.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
WORK -> ToDo[name=Learn, category=WORK, priority=2, date=2022-09-03]
HOME -> ToDo[name=Eat, category=HOME, priority=1, date=2022-08-29]
```

Comment: I don’t know why, but the OP said “highest priority” but both, their posted code and expected output, indicate the *smallest* numbers for priority, i.e. “lowest value for priority”. Besides that, this is another case of “[if `groupingBy` forces you to deal with `Optional`, check whether `toMap` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042622/2711488)” E.g. `.collect( Collectors.toMap(ToDo::category, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.minBy( Comparator.comparingInt(ToDo::priority))))` (or `maxBy` instead of `minBy` whatever the OP actually wants).

Comment: @Holger That's a very good point. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `DOM` should be `HOME`, because that's the category inside your object. I also assume that the `ToDoList` should be an `Optional<ToDo>`.

The `groupingBy` you used will return a `Map<Category, List<ToDo>>`. That's the right key but the wrong value. You need to solve that by also supplying a *downstream* collector, that will collect `ToDo` elements:

```
Map<Category, Optional<ToDo>> result = todo.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                ToDo::getCategory,
                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingInt(ToDo::getPriority))
        ));
```

You can improve the comparator to `Comparator.comparingInt(ToDo::getPriority).thenComparing(ToDo::getDeadline)` to find the entry with the earliest deadline in case some have the same lowest priority.

Note that this will only include entries for categories that are part of your input. If you need all, use an additional loop:

```
for (Category category : Category.values()) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(category, c -> Optional.empty());
}
```