# GroupBy and Stream Filter based on max field for particular record on each date java list

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, collectors, maxby

I am having a `list` that looks like below

```
[
  {
    "busId": "4-3323309834",
    "dataDateTime": "2022-08-27 05:22:46",
    "busName": "27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
    "speedLimit": 80,
    "id": 1,
    "currentSpeed": 67,
    "passengersNo": 80
  },
  {
    "busId": "4-3323309834",
    "dataDateTime": "2022-08-27 07:12:10",
    "busName": "27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
    "speedLimit": 80,
    "id": 2,
    "currentSpeed": 56,
    "passengersNo": 11
  },
  {
    "busId": "4-3323309834",
    "dataDateTime": "2022-08-26 03:12:10",
    "busName": "27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
    "speedLimit": 80,
    "id": 3,
    "currentSpeed": 31,
    "passengersNo": 15
  },
  {
    "busId": "4-3323309834",
    "dataDateTime": "2022-08-26 03:12:10",
    "busName": "27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
    "speedLimit": 80,
    "id": 3,
    "currentSpeed": 78,
    "passengersNo": 15
  },
  {
    "busId": "4-3323309834",
    "dataDateTime": "2022-08-26 04:34:10",
    "busName": "27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
    "speedLimit": 80,
    "id": 7,
    "currentSpeed": 49,
    "passengersNo": 57
  }
]
```

What i would like to achieve is to filter like for example on date `2022-08-27` and also on date `2022-08-26` respectively i only return one record which is having the maximum `currentSpeed` such that my final list looks like below

```
[
  {
    "busId": "4-3323309834",
    "dataDateTime": "2022-08-27 05:22:46",
    "busName": "27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
    "speedLimit": 80,
    "id": 1,
    "currentSpeed": 67,
    "passengersNo": 80
  },
  {
    "busId": "4-3323309834",
    "dataDateTime": "2022-08-26 03:12:10",
    "busName": "27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
    "speedLimit": 80,
    "id": 3,
    "currentSpeed": 78,
    "passengersNo": 15
  }
]
```

Below is how my code looks like and the way i am populating my list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        myList.add(new HashMap<>(Map.of("id", 1,
                "busId","4-3323309834",
                "busName","27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
                "currentSpeed",67,
                "passengersNo",80,
                "speedLimit",80,
                "dataDateTime","2022-08-27 05:22:46")));

        myList.add(new HashMap<>(Map.of("id",2,
                "busId","4-3323309834",
                "busName","27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
                "currentSpeed",56,
                "passengersNo",11,
                "speedLimit",80,
                "dataDateTime","2022-08-27 07:12:10")));

        myList.add(new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                "id",3,
                "busId","4-3323309834",
                "busName","27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
                "currentSpeed",31,
                "passengersNo",15,
                "speedLimit",80,
                "dataDateTime","2022-08-26 03:12:10")));

        myList.add(new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                "id",3,
                "busId","4-3323309834",
                "busName","27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
                "currentSpeed",78,
                "passengersNo",15,
                "speedLimit",80,
                "dataDateTime","2022-08-26 03:12:10")));

        myList.add(new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                "id",7,
                "busId","4-3323309834",
                "busName","27Tr Solaris Single Deck",
                "currentSpeed",49,
                "passengersNo",57,
                "speedLimit",80,
                "dataDateTime","2022-08-26 04:34:10")));

    }
```

Below is what i am trying to use to filter but i a getting `Not a statement` in below filter code

```
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> myList2 = myList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(hashmap ->
                                List.of(hashmap.get("busId"),
                                        hashmap.get("currentSpeed"),
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(HashMap::get("dataDateTime")))));




        System.out.println(Config.ANSI_CYAN + "MyListToJsonPrint: " +
                new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(myList2));
```

Is there an efficient way that i can use to filter

Comment: How you need these date to be provided (varargs, range of dates) ? Also see my comment regarding premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the map having the max `currentSpeed` for each **day**, then you need to group by **day** and map to the hashmap having the max value of current speed. You can use `LocalDateTime` from the `java.time` API to parse your dates so that it is easier to use your map values as a classifier for grouping.

Basically the steps you want are:

- Stream over your list
- collect to map using the date as key
- map to the hashmap having the max value of `currentSpeed` using a `BinaryOperator` and a `Comparator`
- the above steps will result in a `Map<LocalDate, HashMap<String, Object>>`
- and finally get the values from the above map

Code:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

List<HashMap<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>(
        myList.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> LocalDateTime.parse((String) map.get("dataDateTime"), dtf).toLocalDate(),
                                        Function.identity(),
                                        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(map -> (int)map.get("currentSpeed")))))
              .values());

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

You could also use `Collectors.groupingBy` in combination with `Collectors.reducing` but you need then to unwrap the optional resulting from the reducing step

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> result2 = new ArrayList<>(
myList.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map -> LocalDateTime.parse((String) map.get("dataDateTime"), dtf).toLocalDate(),
                                      Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                              Collectors.reducing(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(map -> (int)map.get("currentSpeed")))),
                                              Optional::get))).values());

result2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: with all the data that i have tested its now working okay, nice answer

Comment: can i add you in future questions that may involve stream api

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo Sure, yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would recommend to you to work with POJOs to encapsulate data instead of working with `Map<String, Object>`, because this will make working with the data much more easy and robust as you will not have to worry about extracting values by key and then casting them to the correct data type.

Other than that I can show you a working solution for the problem, that is similar to yours. For my solution I was assuming that each `Map` **always** contains the key `dataDateTime` and `currentSpeed` with valid values. I was also assuming that all dates are in ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
private static List<Map<String, Object>> transform(List<Map<String, Object>> busses, List<LocalDate> dates ){

        return busses.stream()
                // filtering out irrelevant dates
                .filter(bus -> dates.contains(LocalDate.parse(((String) bus.get("dataDateTime")).substring(0, 10))))
                // grouping by the date
                .collect(groupingBy(bus -> ((String) bus.get("dataDateTime")).substring(0, 10)))
                .values().stream()
                // for all busses with the same date get the one that has the max currentSpeed
                .map(sameDateBusses ->
                        sameDateBusses.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(bus -> (Integer) bus.get("currentSpeed"))).get()
                // finally make the Stream a List
                ).toList();
    }
```

You can then call the utility method like this

```
transform(myList, List.of(LocalDate.of(2022, 8, 27), LocalDate.of(2022, 8, 26)));
```

**Please note:** In terms of *efficiency* I am pretty sure the problem can be solved in *linear time.* So if performance is a big deal to you, than there is definitely a better algorithm that you can use.

Comment: i do agree with your recomendations but i did some small benchmarks on when using POJOs and when using Map and i am ready to trade speed with all the pain of getting keys

Comment: is `List<LocalDate> dates` an empty list or a list of all the dates in my map where i have to strip myList of dates and create only a list that has LocalDates

Comment: Well these are the dates you want the maximum `currentSpeed` for, as you explained in your question.

Comment: I also updated my question with a invocation of the method

Comment: yeah well understood so i will have to strip and have a separate list of dates

Comment: well noted on the question update

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo *" i did some small benchmarks on when using POJOs"* - Are you sure that you've properly tested it? Writing a trustworthy benchmark is not an easy thing to accomplish, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java . If it was only a difference between `Instant.now()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` in two places in the code, then it's not something you can trust (please don't get offended if you're done it properly).

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo Such optimization isn't justifiable unless you've figured out that there's a tangible performance issue, which is rooted in the processes of deserialization.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yeah actually my performance improvement was in deserialization and then it reduced the boiler plate code i hade to write for the POJOs, for example if i have 10 POJOs i could just use a map and i dont get to write or even auto generate the POJO classes

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo But was there a **real** performance-issue and was your benchmark thorough enough? I saw many people calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` checks a "benchmark" (sorry if it's not your case).  You've thrown away object but continue using stream, but stream-based solution is no something which gives performance benefits (plain loops are chipper). Also note, class declarations are **not** a boilerplate code by any means. Replacing an object with a `Map` is an antipattern, by doing so you're reducing maintainability of your code.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko i get the following error when using POJO `Cannot resolve method 'toList' in 'Stream`

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo You are getting this error while using [*solution from my answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73609590/17949945). There's no `Stream.toList()` in the code at all. To use `toList()` from the answer above your JDK level should be 16+, you can replace it with `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko i have used `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and that has worked okay

Answer (score 1):

## Update

If you insist on quick and dirty approach using `Map`, that how it can be done (the overall logic is the same as explained below):

```
public static Collection<Map<String, Object>> getFastestByDateInClosedRange(List<Map<String, Object>> routes,
                                                                            LocalDate start,
                                                                            LocalDate end) {
    return routes.stream()
        .filter(busRoute -> isInClosedRange(
            LocalDateTime.parse((String) busRoute.get("dataDateTime"), formatter).toLocalDate(), start, end))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            busRoute -> busRoute.get("dataDateTime"),
            Function.identity(),
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(
                busRoute -> (Integer) busRoute.get("currentSpeed")
            ))
        ))
        .values();
}
```

## Use the Power of Objects

It's an antipattern to treat object related data as a collection of string.

Such practice make your code unfeasible and error-prone. Process marshalling and unmarshalling the data in some cases might involve some degree of complexity, but when you have objects on your hands easier to implement and test any logic you need, it doesn't matter how elaborate it is.

Let's declare an object:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public static class BusRoute {
    private int id;
    private String busId;
    private String busName;
    private int currentSpeed;
    private int speedLimit;
    private LocalDateTime dataDateTime;
}
```

## Parsing JSON

And here's how we can deserialize JSON-array with Gson using `GsonBuilder` and `TypeToken`:

```
String routesJson = """
    [
        // your JSON
    ]""";
        
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString(), formatter);
    }
}).create();
        
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BusRoute>>() {
        }.getType();
        
List<BusRoute> routes = gson.fromJson(routesJson, type);
```

## Fetching the Data with Streams

To find `BusRoute` in the given range of dates, we need to filter the dates, and the group the data into a `Map`. For that purpose we can use *collector* [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) which expects a *mergeFunction* as the third argument.

The same can be done using `groupingBy()`, but it would require two collectors instead of one, and since our goal is to associate a key with a single value and not a collection of value semantically it's the more correct choice (also regarding `groupingBy` vs `toMap` [*see here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041896/java-streams-replacing-groupingby-and-reducing-by-tomap/57042622#57042622)):

```
public static Collection<BusRoute> getFastestByDateInClosedRange(List<BusRoute> routes,
                                                                 LocalDate start,
                                                                 LocalDate end) {
    return routes.stream()
        .filter(busRoute -> isInClosedRange(busRoute.getDataDateTime().toLocalDate(), start, end))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            busRoute -> busRoute.getDataDateTime().toLocalDate(),
            Function.identity(),
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(BusRoute::getCurrentSpeed))
        ))
        .values();
}

public static boolean isInClosedRange(LocalDate candidate, LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    
    return candidate.isEqual(start) || candidate.isEqual(end) ||
        candidate.isAfter(start) && candidate.isBefore(end);
}
```

The following line

```
getFastestByDateInClosedRange(routes, LocalDate.parse("2022-08-26"), LocalDate.parse("2022-08-27"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*with would give the following output for sample data provided in the question:*

```
GroupOfSetsUniqueCombinations.BusRoute(id=1, busId=4-3323309834, busName=27Tr Solaris Single Deck, currentSpeed=67, speedLimit=80, dataDateTime=2022-08-27T05:22:46)
GroupOfSetsUniqueCombinations.BusRoute(id=3, busId=4-3323309834, busName=27Tr Solaris Single Deck, currentSpeed=78, speedLimit=80, dataDateTime=2022-08-26T03:12:10)
```