# Stream.max() on a set of elements from a stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, max

I have a java `List` of `CodeObj`. `CodeObj` has 2 attributes : `codeName` and `version`.
My java `List` looks like this when mapped to a `JSON` object :

```
[
    { "codeName": "test1", "version": "1" },

    { "codeName": "test1", "version": "2" },

    { "codeName": "test1", "version": "3" },

    { "codeName": "test2", "version": "1" },

    { "codeName": "test2", "version": "2" },

    { "codeName": "test2", "version": "3" },

    { "codeName": "test2", "version": "4" },
]
```

I would like to filter this `List` by each `codeName` most recent `version` in java, so it would give this result when mapped to a JSON object :

```
[
    { "codeName": "test1", "version": "3" },

    { "codeName": "test2", "version": "4" },
]
```

To make it, I have to use the `Stream` java class and its methods like `filter`, `map`, `max`, etc.

I started with this bit of code :

```
codeObjs.stream()
.max(Comparator.comparing(CodeObj::getVersion))
```

I feel like I have to isolate each set of `CodeObj` that has the same `codeName`, but I don't know how to do it while turning the `List` into a `Stream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
return codeObjs.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                CodeObj::getCodeName,
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(CodeObj::getVersion))
            ))
            .values().stream()
            .flatMap(Optional::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, basically, you are isolating each instance of `CodeObj` with a unique name by using `Collectors.groupingBy`. Then using `Collectors.maxBy` on each group, you get the highest version. Then, by streaming the resulting map, you access collections of `Optional<CodeObj>` instances, which represent the highest versions per group. `flatMap(Optional::stream)` transforms these `Optionals` into a sequence of `CodeObj`. Finally, you collect them into a list through `Collectors.toList()`

Comment: Slightly simpler when using `toMap` instead of `groupingBy`, e.g. `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(CodeObj::getCodeName, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing( CodeObj::getVersion))), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));`

Answer (score 1):

Given the following class:

```
class CodeObj {
    private String codeName;
    private String version;

    public CodeObj(String codeName, String version) {
        this.codeName = codeName;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getCodeName() {
        return codeName;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CodeObj = [%s, %s]".formatted(codeName, version);
    }

}
```

With the initial list of objects.

```
List<CodeObj> codeObjs = List.of(new CodeObj("test1", "1"),
        new CodeObj("test1", "2"), new CodeObj("test1", "3"),
        new CodeObj("test2", "1"), new CodeObj("test2", "2"),
        new CodeObj("test2", "3"), new CodeObj("test2", "4"));
```

Here is a max filter which can either be declared separately as shown or put in-line with the stream. It compares each version and returns the object with the latest.

```
BinaryOperator<CodeObj> latestVersion = (co1, co2) -> co1.getVersion()
        .compareTo(co2.getVersion()) > 0 ? co1 : co2;
```

And here is the solution.  The CodeObj objects are reduced to the required max versions and the resulting `Collection` is remapped to an `ArrayList`.

```
List<CodeObj> results = codeObjs.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.groupingBy(CodeObj::getCodeName,
                Collectors.reducing(new CodeObj("", ""), latestVersion)),
                mp->new ArrayList<>(mp.values())));


results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
CodeObj = [test2, 4]
CodeObj = [test1, 3]
```

Comment: Note that the `toMap` collector already has the logic of `groupingBy` and `reducing`, see also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967784/stream-max-on-a-set-of-elements-from-a-stream#comment135704380_76967864) or [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57041896/2711488)

Comment: @Holger Had never noticed that `BinaryOperator` had those static methods.  Thanks for pointing it out.